# How to type a function that accepts an array of objects with a specific type for value of key K

Tags: typescript

I need to type a signature of a generic function that takes in input an array of objects and 3 column names of this object:

```js
function myFunction<T, K extends keyof T>(
  dataset: T[],
  propertyOne: K,
  propertyTwo: K,
  propertyThird: K
): {
  ...
}
```

This works but I need now to be more specific about the type of the value of column `propertyTwo`.
In fact thise value can be only string.

So the datum of type `T` is something like this:

```js
T {
  [propertyOne]: any
  [propertyTwo]: string
  [propertyThird]: any
  [x?: string]: any
}
```

Example:

```js
const dataset = [{age: 23, name: 'josh', country: 'america'}, ...]
myFunction(dataset, 'age', 'name', 'country')
```

How can I do that?

I tried this:

```js
function myFunction<T, K extends keyof T, C extends string>(
  dataset: T[],
  propertyOne: K,
  propertyTwo: K, // how can I use C?
  propertyThird: K
): {
  ...
}
```

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/Nl23xW) meet your needs? If so, I could write up an answer (after checking for duplicates).  If not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz. It's interesting, thanks. Can you explain KeysMatching? It's not very clear to me. It seems very complicated

Comment: I would be happy to explain if I write up an answer; could you tell me if it works for you or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, if you have different requirements or intents for what you do with `propertyOne`, `propertyTwo`, and `propertyThreeThird`, then they should probably each have their own [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type parameters.  Otherwise the compiler will just infer your single type argument to be a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of the three literal types, and there'd be no way to figure out which member corresponds to `propertyTwo`.  So we can refactor to:

```
function myFunction<
  T,
  K1 extends keyof T,
  K2 extends keyof T,
  K3 extends keyof T
>(
  dataset: T[],
  propertyOne: K1,
  propertyTwo: K2,
  propertyThird: K3
) {
  
}
```

---

Now we can represent the constraint where the property type of `T` at key `K2` must be `string`.  The easy way to do this is to add a recursive [constraint](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) on `T`, by saying that it must be assignable to `Record<K2, string>` (using [the `Record<K, V>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkeystype) to represent a type with keys `K` and values `V`):

```
function myFunction<
  T extends Record<K2, string>, // add constraint
  K1 extends keyof T,
  K2 extends keyof T,
  K3 extends keyof T
>(
  dataset: T[],
  propertyOne: K1,
  propertyTwo: K2,
  propertyThird: K3
) {
  dataset.forEach(x => x[propertyTwo].toUpperCase()); // okay
}
const dataset = [{ age: 23, name: 'josh', country: 'america' }]

const okay = myFunction(dataset, 'age', 'name', 'country'); // okay
const bad = myFunction(dataset, 'name', 'age', 'country'); // error!
// ------------------> ~~~~~~~
```

This works as desired.  Inside the implementation of `myFunction`, the compiler knows that each element of `dataset` has a `string`-valued property at the key `propertyTwo`.

And callers are also given an error if the argument passed for `propertyTwo` doesn't correspond to a `string` property on the elements of `dataset`.  Hooray!

---

The only issue is that callers probably would rather see the error on `'age'` and not on `dataset`, and would also like reasonable IntelliSense so that they are prompted with only the key names corresponding to `string` properties.  If you want that, you can modify the constraint on `K2`.

First we need a utility type `KeysMatching<T, V>` which computes the keys of `T` whose properties are assignable to `V`. There's no built-in utility or functionality that works this way (there is a request at [microsoft/TypeScript#48992](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/48992) for a native version of this that the compiler understands well) so we need to build it.  Here's one way to build it:

```
type KeysMatching<T extends object, V> = keyof {
  [K in keyof T as T[K] extends V ? K : never]: any
};
```

What I'm doing here is using [key remapping in mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html#key-remapping-via-as) to map `T` to a new type which only has keys `K` where `T[K] extends V`.  So if `T` is `{age: number, name: string, country: string}` and `V` is `string`, then that mapped type is `{name: string, country: string}`.  And then we get its keys with [the `keyof` operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/keyof-types.html#the-keyof-type-operator), so that would be `"name" | "country"`.

And now instead of `K2 extends keyof T`, we write `K2 extends KeysMatching<T, string>`:

```
function myFunction<
  T extends Record<K2, string>,
  K1 extends keyof T,
  K2 extends KeysMatching<T, string>,
  K3 extends keyof T
>(
  dataset: T[],
  propertyOne: K1,
  propertyTwo: K2,
  propertyThird: K3
) {
  dataset.forEach(x => x[propertyTwo].toUpperCase());
}
const dataset = [{ age: 23, name: 'josh', country: 'america' }]

const okay = myFunction(dataset, 'age', 'name', 'country');
const bad = myFunction(dataset, 'name', 'age', 'country'); // error!
// -----------------------------------> ~~~~~
```

There you go. Now the constraint is enforced and you get the error where you want it!

---

It might seem redundant that `T` is constrained to `Record<K2, string>` and `K2` is constrained to `KeysMatching<T, string>` (they are, conceptually, the same constraint), but unfortunately the compiler cannot understand what `K2 extends KeysMatching<T, string>` implies inside the implementation of `myFunction()`... so if you remove the `T extends Record<K2, string>` constraint, you get this:

```
function myFunction<
  T,
  K1 extends keyof T,
  K2 extends KeysMatching<T, string>,
  K3 extends keyof T
>(
  dataset: T[],
  propertyOne: K1,
  propertyTwo: K2,
  propertyThird: K3
) {
  dataset.forEach(x => x[propertyTwo].toUpperCase()); // error!
  // -------------------------------> ~~~~~~~~~~~
  // Property 'toUpperCase' does not exist on type 'T[K2]'
}
```

This is why microsoft/TypeScript#48992 exists; if a native `KeysMatching` existed, presumably you could write just `K2 extends KeysMatching<T, string>` and the compiler would still understand that `T[K2]` must be assignable to `string`.  But this doesn't exist, so the redundant constraint is useful.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEApeIA2AvJBvAUPkkqJLAsgPIBOAlgOZ5HFIBmArsPAC60D2wJGACeAMU49+wADwAVADRIA0kggAPbhGAATKEgDWEYX1ZJZAPgAUzFkm0huIKBG4AuMwG0AuvJssY1HwwENTcwpTAEO5KvrbEAUEhYbIA7nzRsXEJwaHCsgAWtNTa0X4AlEx+AL7MNcyk0HCISABKEKwI3HzUEcgEfhxcvAJCYhLDMn7EClPKAIyqGlq6BkYmZpm2SgBMi5o6eobGpjNxygDMe8uHayd+VrP2js5unj6z2UnhkdFzm-6BHLJNLRbb-eKAr4FIolC7lJhnJ5OFwAOlY3QAogh8pY1EgALzmJBqDyfXKpPheFFdACqMByAGFkZYymUANxIAD0nNU1EC1EUYWCSHWJLJwMpSFoekAfBuAdl3ALAEgCEyQDwf9U-PABFBuHYHMidfikB5cEgQPQokhtudFA13AByABWfCg+Ttik1nG41GE9vAIVo6DtSCqXkItk1wG1Iv0IGEBNG4iGUksSJeijtZogbqQdoa2btHuAXuEdvZXJ5fBjwg1Wp1ACMQNp4yJE5IBCm9Wmc3n05n84Xi6WOdySHxefzamGSH7yM02h0eN0KZVbIM24IW+MpNJZrIrgdWhBNcVpDtFNq6MB6OZFCPG02IxeQLQi7MlAt1PsVkd1qc4jt92-W4NjfS5P2uVZjjMe5rERTsXHcWRvHBJBxW+C13xQtCKVBLDIXJQpimic54QIODnlRdFqCxeAcTxQliVJfCJSpWl6RCJlnBZMsR0rWN1XDWtdQog0jRNTN3CtG0-XtJ0XWzAdvV9SA6EDYNQxrSMdT4uNDU3JN21TFxe3NfMexzRSSx4isq00qMGybPSxgM4AOxE9NzIzUz00sody3HboAEI-BHABacKIsiqKIqJAA-eKEtiyd6hnJpkFEF9MFEbowARFghWQJQjCgABZBxaJfeg5EAvQ+DrB0j24RQADUiUNH9TDIuIPBUF9IN-U09CQpQvBqpBmqQAB+ZQkHcSIADcQi8dwQGAatbCqNkp2INcJgTLcBB3M493Ag82mPbRTzBJAL0qm83w-JYDw6kCzgA06ViK4RSvKworzkc8vTulClDAp6gKg2QYMeeDXiQ94zjQ3pfjwxJyRBZQwQ+Zi8kI2FQdImGRLRTFsVxAkiTFHGKVYvg6UZZlWS2ja7J1IzRONU1zUk61p0gWTnVdd0+E9JScz9VSQCDENtqQR9tKrZtnPXNz9RMrMPL9fsRaLb0h1ZpAHKV1sJlVrtcy19XtdFqzhx5EJ+WCqc6hSsg0qQAA5PhuAARXYWhNDy4gCuUYqyu4Cr-pO8HavqxqWra-rOtmHqpUEF69ycTwRrGibppUOaIEW6hltNNbqi2gYDo3ZWJiOuI-y2R6vxuSGQd2D69C+n6I7+qqFBuoGr3ut6wZbpPoNsB5yP1RDkOxtGwmR+ZUaBPIMbPBe1+hIi4VsCoutsdmSeosn6MppjF-XylqTp9jqE4iBuLtgLqGCs4wuir-v5-uLEv-pKH8eQAAUcY5jYgzZwQZtB8GgKOHU6hpTaUECHO0w1theDtAJFg8thL6njJzCSlpea2hzHJIWcsdbFmUv6NSMsDY6WNtXM2xlxbeW7JbCyVC9bsgNkbJyJtkzs01pAfMfYfLcNtv5B2QVCCTiqEAA)